# Erro 403 ao efetuar upload aws s3 .net

Tags: .net, amazon-aws

> Bastou Configurar as permissões do usuário no S3 e tudo funcionou perfeitamente!

Estou construindo uma função para upload de imagens no serviço s3 da amazon porém estou com um erro 403, existe alguma configuração adicional que devo fazer no meu S3?

```
            TransferUtility fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(code, keyCode, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USWest2);

            var uploadRequest = new Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtilityUploadRequest();

            string filename = File.FileName;

            uploadRequest.InputStream = File.InputStream;
            uploadRequest.BucketName = "kasne";
            uploadRequest.Key = filename;
            uploadRequest.StorageClass = Amazon.S3.S3StorageClass.ReducedRedundancy;
            uploadRequest.CannedACL = Amazon.S3.S3CannedACL.PublicRead;

            //faz o upload.
            fileTransferUtility.Upload(uploadRequest);

            return filename;
```

Comment: Em geral o erro 403 é referente a permissão para executar determinadas ações, verifique algumas possibilidades...Talvez seu Firewall esteja barrando a aplicação, ou o Proxy, ou permissões de seu usuário no servidor, enfim, algo a ver com privilégios e permissões.

Comment: Obrigado, consegui fazer o upload e também download. Estava faltando dar permissões no usuário que tenho no S3! Bastou adicionar as permissões e o método que criei funcionou perfeitamente! Obrigado pela ajuda!